# A cocos 2D code animation that does the same thing that core animation

Tags: iphone, xcode, animation, cocos2d-iphone, core-animation

I would like to use this Core Animation code in Cocos2D, or I just would like to have the same result.How can I translate it to cocos 2D:

```
CABasicAnimation *pulseAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];
pulseAnimation.duration = 1.0;
pulseAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.1];
pulseAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
pulseAnimation.autoreverses = YES;
pulseAnimation.repeatCount = FLT_MAX;
CALayer *layer = centre.layer;
[layer addAnimation:pulseAnimation forKey:nil];
```

Thank You. SOrry for my english I'm french :/

Comment: You really need to go and do some learning about cocos2D. You can't keep posting chunks of code and asking for people to translate it for cocos2D. That's not what Stack Overflow is for - please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). We will help you and guide you, but we aren't here to do your work for you. Go and read some tutorials (I gave you some links previously) and read the cocos2d documentation and API. It's not that difficult once you get started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
id scl = [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:1 scale:1.1];
id action = [CCSequence actionOne:scl two:[scl reverse]];
[YOUR_CCOBJECT runAction:action];
```

this is the code for a single pulse (scale to 110% then back to 100%)

there is `[action setRepeatCount:YOUR_COUNT];` but I haven't tried that myself.

Comment: With id action = [CCSequence actionOne:scl two:[scl reverse]]; the code doesn't work I don't know why. my app stop

Comment: CCSequence doesn't have "actionOne: two:". CCSequence is used as `[CCSequence actions:firstAction, secondAction, nil]'`

Comment: it doesn't work too with [CCSequence actions:firstAction, secondAction, nil]'

Comment: What object are you calling `runAction` on?

Comment: @gregrock Update your question to include the code that you have in your code section where you are doing this action

Comment: @NickBull it does have "actionOne: two:" http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.5/interface_c_c_sequence.html
you might be using a different version.